# Autoquery distinct results with related records

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have the following related POCO entities saved in SQLite.

```
public class Customer
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Reference]
    public List<Order> CustomerOrders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}
```

Using the following AutoQuery with inner join

```
public class AutoQueryRequest : QueryBase<Customer>, IJoin<Customer, Order>
{
}
```

If I have 1 Customer record with 3 related Order records, the inner join query returns 3 records of Customer (as expected). Since the Orders are already included in the Customer entity, how can I make the AutoQuery to return only distinct Customer records (1 in this case)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to join on the Order table to load OrmLite POCO References as they're loaded automatically, so your AutoQuery Service just needs to Query the Customer parent POCO, e.g:

```
public class QueryCustomers : QueryBase<Customer> {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried using the query for Customers but was not able to search for fields within Orders. For example, if I wanted to get all Customer records (with related Orders) who have Orders with Types "A", "B" and "C", i tried using /QueryCustomers?CustomerOrderTypes=A,B,C but it doesn't work. Do I have to use any custom AutoQuery implementation?

Comment: @nivjen No that wouldn't allow you Query Orders, you would need a custom AutoQuery implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In that case do I have to use an inner join between Customer and Order entities? Any pointers to example/documentation would be great!